# When considering the acceleration as constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I'm solving a simple dynamic exercise, exercise says:
"What is the absolute value of the force necessary to speed up a 500kg mass subject to 1600km/h in 1,8s, with the object from rest?"

Then I had the following problem: Some resolutions use
`a = ΔV / ΔT`
 
but the exercise **doesn't say that the acceleration is constant** and I used:
`Vf = Vo + at`
What is the correct way?

Comment: It seems to be implied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question implies that acceleration is constant. Newton's second law states:

$F=ma$ (for constant mass $m$)

The fact that he asked for "the" force, implies that it's a constant force, and a constant force would result in constant acceleration of the body.

the two above expressions you wrote for constant acceleration are equivalent:

$a$=$\Delta v\over\Delta t$ = $\frac {v_{f}-v_{i}}{t_{f}-t_{i}}$, multiplying by both sides one gets :

$a(t_{f}-t_{i})=v_{f}-v_{i}$, since by convetion we set $t_{i}=0$ and $t_{f}=t$ therefore:
$at=v_{f}-v_{i}$
rearranging you get:
$v_{f}=v_{i}+at$

so choose whatever expression you like, they are the same.

In fact if this question asks for the value of the force with acceleration being non-constant(without giving you any further information than $v(1.8)=1000$ km/hr and $v(0)=0$), then you'd have infinite values for $F$.

For a particle to have a non-constant acceleration(that is for $a$ to be function of time $a(t)$), the position function of the object $x(t)$ has to be a polynomial of at least degree 3 or higher(or it could be infinitely differentiable function like $sin(t)$).To get the acceleration function from the position function, one differentiates the latter two times with respect to time(if $x(t)$ is polynomial of degree 2 or less, then by the time you differentiate two times you will get a constant $a$).

To get your $F$, first you differentiate $x(t)$ with time to get $v(t)$.If your position function is of degree higher than 2, then you get $v(t)$ as a polynomial function of at least degree 2 or higher. then you will solve $v(1.8)=1000$ km/h and  $v(0)=0$. With these two pieces of information, you'll notice that it's impossible to find the unique coefficients that determine $v(t)$, since they are infinite in number, consequently you won't be able to find $a(t)$ with unique coefficients.

and hence $F(t)=ma(t)$ will have infinitely many values.

So the fact that he only gave you two pieces of information $v(0)=0$ and $v(1.8)=1000$ km/hr, and He wants the "absolute value of the force" implies that it's a constant acceleration ,otherwise you won't be able to find that force.

Answer (score -2):

"a = ΔV / ΔT" and "Vf = Vo + at" are the same really.

ΔV is Vf - Vo, otherwise known as "Change in Velocity"

So..

Vf = Vo + at

at = Vf - Vo

a = (Vf - Vo)/t

a = ΔV/ΔT

To calculate the Force required,

a = ΔV/ΔT

F = m*a or a = F/m

F/m = ΔV/ΔT

F = (ΔV*m)/ΔT

Comment: While true, this doesn't really help the OP any. They want to know why/when the acceleration can be assumed to be constant.

Comment: My apologies, forgot to answer that part.